# What is KDE ? how to implement application for cloud

Tags: server, kde, cloud

I have some questions I searched for it but couldn't found any answer to them.

1. What is KDE? I heard that captures frames of what application that runs under it? If it does, could someone explain me more about it?
2. I want to make how to make application for cloud server?  Which version of ubuntu needs to be installed?
3. Is KDE able to run on cloud server ?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. While it is your first time here, I have to note that your question is not on par with community standards. Feel free to read the F.A.Q [here](http://askubuntu.com/faq). In the future, as a general guideline, try to put some effort into researching your questions a little bit, and also try to ask one question per topic. That allows possible answers and future readers to be more focused on the topic and less confused as to the Question's context. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. [KDE](http://www.kde.org/) stands for the **K Desktop Environment**. It is a GUI,
   meaning a layer that provides a sustainable look and feel at the
   linux desktop.
2. If you would like to work with Servers, I recommend picking an LTS
   (Long Term Support) version of Ubuntu. As is now, Version 10.04 and
   Version 12.04 seem to be a fine choice. If you would like to write
   an application, you need to learn how to program, something which is
   out of the scope of this question.
3. Yes it is, and you could be able to see it if you connect via
   **ssh** to your server with the following flag: `ssh -X user@domain <port>`

**NOTE:** [Wikipedia in particular notes about the name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE):

> The K was originally suggested to stand for "Kool", but it was quickly
>   decided that the K should stand for nothing in particular. The KDE
>   initialism is therefore expanded to "K Desktop Environment".